# Custom contact form 7 select with custom values

Tags: custom-field, plugin-contact-form-7, select

I have been searching for a way to add a select field to the Contact form with custom data.

The goal is to have a form where someone can ask for information on an article by selecting the article with a select field.

What I did figure out is how to add the custom select field to the form with a filter

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag_data_option', function($n, $options, $args){
    // special data provider tag found ?
    if (in_array('press_posts', $options)){
        $data = array('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3');
        return $data;
    }
    // default - do not apply any changes within the options
    return null;
}, 10, 3);
```

Now I only have to adde the following shortcode to the form

```
[select press_post include_blank id:press_select data:press_posts]
```

The only issue I am having with this is that this results in the following html.

```
<select name="press_post" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" id="press_select">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
    <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
    <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see the `Test1` value has a capital letter just like the others.
This is something I don't want and I would like to set the value myself.

I tried adding keys to the data array but that did not do anything.

Hope you guys can help me out.

**** EDIT ****

I currently got it working at a somewhat different way.

```
function dynamic_field_values($tag){

    if ( $tag['name'] != 'press_post' )
        return $tag;

    $args = array (
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'press_posts',
        'orderby'       => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
    );

    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);

    if ( ! $custom_posts )
        return $tag;

    foreach ( $custom_posts as $custom_post ) {

        $tag['raw_values'][] = $custom_post->post_title;
        $tag['values'][] = $custom_post->ID;
        $tag['labels'][] = $custom_post->post_title;

    }

    return $tag;
};

 add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_field_values', 10, 2);
```

Currently just working out how I can get more data in the function so I can make this all dynamic.

If anyone knows how to do that it would be great if you could share that info with me :)

anyways how I want to call the field in Contact Form 7 is like this

```
[contact-form-7 id="9778" title="Press contact" number_of_posts="34" post_type="in_het_nieuws"]
```

Note the `number_of_posts` and the `post_type` parts.

Comment: in which filter do you hook the function `dynamic_field_values` ?

Comment: @mmm I added it to the edit. but it is wpcf7_form_tag

Comment: I edited my answer for your 2nd question

Answer (score 3):

You can set the values with the filter `wpcf7_form_tag` and add the shortcode attributes with the filter `shortcode_atts_wpcf7`

```
add_filter("wpcf7_form_tag", function($scanned_tag, $replace){


    if ("press_post" === $scanned_tag["name"]) {

        $contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

        $number_of_posts = $contact_form->shortcode_attr("number_of_posts");
        $post_type = $contact_form->shortcode_attr("post_type");


        // using $number_of_posts and $post_type here


        $scanned_tag['raw_values'] = [
            "number_of_posts \"$number_of_posts\" - post_type \"$post_type\" | val 1",
            "Test 2|val 2",
            "Test 3|val 3",
        ];

        $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($scanned_tag['raw_values']);

        $scanned_tag['values'] = $pipes->collect_befores();
        $scanned_tag['pipes'] = $pipes;

    }


    return $scanned_tag;

}, 10, 2);


add_filter("shortcode_atts_wpcf7", function ($out, $pairs, $atts, $shortcode) {

    foreach (["number_of_posts", "post_type"] as $a) {

        if (isset($atts[$a])) {
            $out[$a] = $atts[$a];
        }

    }

    return $out;

}, 10, 4);
```

there is always "Test 2" in the HTML code but CF7 replace the value with "val 2" in the e-mail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. though I got it working and changed my answer just as you are answering you did clear up some things that I really was wondering about. regarding the pipes and the `raw_values` part. Thank you for that. and thank you for your input. I am still left with a small challenge though (explained in the updated question) if you would have the time :) cheers