# Working with Contact Form 7 pipes

Tags: shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I am trying to add some custom code to my Contact Form 7 for a career form and make it work with the [pipe integrated system](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/).

I have created a shortcode that get my custom post type `career` and generate a select menu based on Contact Form 7 syntax.

My goal is to be able to make the pipe system working witin my shortchode.

First, I added a filter to be able to generate all the shortcodes inside Contact Form 7

I inserted this code in `functions.php` :

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements' );
function mycustom_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) {
    $form = do_shortcode( $form );
    return $form;
}
```

After this, I went in my Administration and edited the Contact Form 7 with this part of code :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="residence" class="required">Please select</label>
[batisseurs_jobs]
</div>
```

This select will loop on the custom post type career and display the job list in a select. The code looks like this so far :

```
public function batisseurs_emplois( $atts, $content ) {

    // args
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'career',
        'orderby'               => 'menu_order',
        'order'                 => 'ASC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = array();

    $html[] = sprintf(
        '<option value>%s</option>',
        __("---", "wheels")
    ); 

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // ACF
        $localisations = get_field('disponibilite_du_poste');


        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($localisations); $i++) { 

            $localisation = $localisations[$i];

            $html[] = sprintf(
                '<option value="%s|%s">%s</option>',
                get_the_title($query->ID) . ' - ' . $localisation['nom_de_la_residence'],
                $localisation['contact_principal'],
                get_the_title($query->ID) . ' - ' . $localisation['nom_de_la_residence']
            );
        }

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return '<label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-302"><select name="menu-302" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="residence" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">' . implode( '', $html ) . '</select></span></label>';
}
```

The output HTML looks like this :

```
<select name="menu-302" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="residence" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
       <option value="">---</option>
       <option value="Job title - City|email@domain.com">Job title - City</option>
       <option value="Job title - City|email@domain.com">Job title - City</option>
</select>
```

You can see that I am trying to use the [pipe system](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) inside the shortchode.

But when I write in the To: field [menu-302] I get an error because it try to send to an unspecified value I guess.

I think so because when I create the same thing directly in the Contact Form7 editor, the Email / pipe email is not displayed in the output HTML.

Does some 1 know how I could get it working or I am better to just do raw PHP ?

Comment: you can see here how to add custom value in the dropdown : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/279975/custom-contact-form-7-select-with-custom-values#answer-280004

Comment: Sweet! At the first read, it looks like this code may fix my problem.